# How to fix broken GTK styles

Tags: xfce, gtk

I've been trying to minimise the footprint of an Xfce-4.10 Raspbian system which will be used as a Chromium kiosk. As part of this, I had previously removed packages related to GTK, Xfce themes, plymouth-themes etc.

At some point, my GTK apps stopped properly rendering GTK widgets ([example](http://smg.photobucket.com/user/Darvids0n/media/brokenGTK.png.html)). Notice the Xfce Session and Startup window renders fine, whereas the NetworkManager/GTK menu has no spacing or dividers.

A similar issue is encountered viewing Onboard settings. Checkboxes are not visible, although pressing where they should be shows a tick. Tabs are only visible by their text and function properly as tabs.

What steps can I take to reinstall/reconfigure GTK? There are no GTK-related settings in `~/.config`, I have reinstalled all base xfce4 packages and `gtk2-engines-xfce`/`gtk3-engines-xfce`, as well as reinstalling `adwaita-icon-theme` and switching themes in Appearance Settings.

Comment: Having this exact issue (well I think so; sounds right) with xfce4 on a new 18.04 installation. Sublime Text 3 (for example) works fine in Unity but the application menu is squished when launched under xfce.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, also from trying to slim it down.

To fix it, I installed [gtk2-engines](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/gtk-engines.html), [gtk2-engines-pixbuf](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gtk2-engines-pixbuf), and [gtk3-engines-breeze](https://packages.debian.org/buster/gtk3-engines-breeze), then went to theme manager, changed the current theme, went to window manager, changed the theme there, and got it fixed.